# Interference pattern of relativistic particles

Tags: quantum-mechanics, special-relativity, particle-physics, double-slit-experiment, wave-particle-duality

I wanted to know if it is possible to perform a double slit experiment with electrons travelling at 0.99c as the wavelength is very short.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you mean in principle or in practice? In principle the answer is "yes, even fast electrons can in principle be brought into a state with a superposition of directions of motion which would lead to interference fringes." In practice the answer is "the short wavelength makes it very difficult." At $0.99c$ for electrons I find the wavelength is around $10^{-42}\,$m. This is a lot smaller than the Planck length so it is very hard to suggest how to form a structure to act as 'slits' or, more generally, how to form a pair of collimated beams at a slight angle or how to detect the interference.

Comment: So what is the smallest wavelength we could work with in practice and what would be the energies would be like?Does special relativity come into the play?

Comment: If you don't mind could you show me how to do the calculations